# Pushing new objects replaces previous object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to push a element children text to my object reminder by passing it to to the new reminder method, but it doesn't push each of the element text it just replaces them.

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-reminder-button', function() {
    var value = $(this).siblings('input').val(); //get the value of input
    var title = $(this).siblings('h1').text(value); //set the h1 
    var saveSetName = $(this).parent().siblings().children('input').val();
    var elem = $(this).parent().parent().children(".reminder-lists").children(); //get the reminder-lists children
    $(elem).each(function(i, e) {
        var txt = $(e).text(); //set txt to the elem text node
        saveSetName = new ReminderSet(saveSetName)
            .add(new Reminder(txt)) //create new reminder to push to reminders array

    });

})



var ReminderSet = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.reminders = [];
}

ReminderSet.prototype.add = function(reminder) {
    this.reminders.push(reminder);
    console.log(this.name, this.reminders); 
    return this;
}

ReminderSet.prototype.list = function() {
    console.log(this.reminders);
}

var Reminder = function(description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

Comment: `new ReminderSet` that creates a new object with an empty array. You need to save your original one and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you create a ReminderSet object for each pushing element. Create the object once. Like this,

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-reminder-button', function() {
    var value = $(this).siblings('input').val(); //get the value of input
    var title = $(this).siblings('h1').text(value); //set the h1 
    var saveSetName = $(this).parent().siblings().children('input').val();
    var elem = $(this).parent().parent().children(".reminder-lists").children(); //get the reminder-lists children
    saveSetName = new ReminderSet(saveSetName);
    $(elem).each(function(i, e) {
        var txt = $(e).text(); //set txt to the elem text node
        saveSetName.add(new Reminder(txt)) //create new reminder to push to reminders array

    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
saveSetName = new ReminderSet(saveSetName)
        .add(new Reminder(txt))
```

You're just replacing the value of the old object with that new value, in order for it to work the way you want it you have to declare a new variable, outside the `for` loop:

```
var reminderSet = new ReminderSet(saveSetName);
```

And once you're inside your loop you can then add your reminders:

```
$(elem).each(function(i, e) {
    var txt = $(e).text(); //set txt to the elem text node
    reminderSet.add(new Reminder(txt))
});
```